# test rocket chip util 'Arbiters.scala', got error 'bits operated ... must be hardware ..."

Tags: chisel

I copied a rocket-chip util module 'Arbiters.scala' to a separate work directory, test with the following code:

```
object try_arbiter extends App {
  chisel3.Driver.execute(args, () => new HellaCountingArbiter(UInt(4.W), 3, 5))
}
```

There's no problem when compiling. However, in the step 'Elaborating design...', it reported `[error] chisel3.core.Binding$ExpectedHardwareException: mux condition 'chisel3.core.Bool@46' must be hardware, not a bare Chisel type"`

The related code is

```
PriorityEncoder(io.in.map(_.valid))
```

when I change this line to the following one, the error's gone (the scala code still has this kind of errs, but not in this line).

```
PriorityEncoder(io.in.map(x => Wire(x.valid)))
```

The rocket chip codes should have been evaluated for many times, right? I think there must have sth I have missed... Some configurations?

Thank you for any hints!

Appendix(the Arbiters.scala):

```
package rocket_examples

import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._

/** A generalized locking RR arbiter that addresses the limitations of the
 *  version in the Chisel standard library */
abstract class HellaLockingArbiter[T <: Data](typ: T, arbN: Int, rr: Boolean = false)
    extends Module {

  val io = new Bundle {
    val in = Vec(arbN, Decoupled(typ.cloneType)).flip
    val out = Decoupled(typ.cloneType)
  }

  def rotateLeft[T <: Data](norm: Vec[T], rot: UInt): Vec[T] = {
    val n = norm.size
    Vec.tabulate(n) { i =>
      Mux(rot < UInt(n - i), norm(UInt(i) + rot), norm(rot - UInt(n - i)))
    }
  }

  val lockIdx = Reg(init = UInt(0, log2Up(arbN)))
  val locked = Reg(init = Bool(false))

  val choice = if (rr) {
    PriorityMux(
      rotateLeft(Vec(io.in.map(_.valid)), lockIdx + UInt(1)),
      rotateLeft(Vec((0 until arbN).map(UInt(_))), lockIdx + UInt(1)))
  } else {
    PriorityEncoder(io.in.map(_.valid))
  }

  val chosen = Mux(locked, lockIdx, choice)

  for (i <- 0 until arbN) {
    io.in(i).ready := io.out.ready && chosen === UInt(i)
  }

  io.out.valid := io.in(chosen).valid
  io.out.bits := io.in(chosen).bits
}

/** This locking arbiter determines when it is safe to unlock
 *  by peeking at the data */
class HellaPeekingArbiter[T <: Data](
      typ: T, arbN: Int,
      canUnlock: T => Bool,
      needsLock: Option[T => Bool] = None,
      rr: Boolean = false)
    extends HellaLockingArbiter(typ, arbN, rr) {

  def realNeedsLock(data: T): Bool =
    needsLock.map(_(data)).getOrElse(Bool(true))

  when (io.out.fire()) {
    when (!locked && realNeedsLock(io.out.bits)) {
      lockIdx := choice
      locked := Bool(true)
    }
    // the unlock statement takes precedent
    when (canUnlock(io.out.bits)) {
      locked := Bool(false)
    }
  }
}

/** This arbiter determines when it is safe to unlock by counting transactions */
class HellaCountingArbiter[T <: Data](
      typ: T, arbN: Int, count: Int,
      val needsLock: Option[T => Bool] = None,
      rr: Boolean = false)
    extends HellaLockingArbiter(typ, arbN, rr) {

  def realNeedsLock(data: T): Bool =
    needsLock.map(_(data)).getOrElse(Bool(true))

  // if count is 1, you should use a non-locking arbiter
  require(count > 1, "CountingArbiter cannot have count <= 1")

  val lock_ctr = Counter(count)

  when (io.out.fire()) {
    when (!locked && realNeedsLock(io.out.bits)) {
      lockIdx := choice
      locked := Bool(true)
      lock_ctr.inc()
    }

    when (locked) {
      when (lock_ctr.inc()) { locked := Bool(false) }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that almost all of the code in rocket-chip has been written against older Chisel2-style APIs and should be compiled with the compatibility wrapper `import Chisel._`. I see you used `import chisel3._` which has somewhat stricter semantics.

For this specific case, the difference between Chisel2 and Chisel3 is that ports (`val io`) must be wrapped in `IO(...)`, ie.

```
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Flipped(Vec(arbN, Decoupled(typ)))
    val out = Decoupled(typ)
  })
```

Note that I also changed `Vec(arbN, Decoupled(typ.cloneType)).flip` to `Flipped(Vec(arbN, Decoupled(typ)))` and removed the `.cloneType` on `val out`. The latter two changes are not required for this to compile but they will be flagged as deprecation warnings as of Chisel 3.1.2.